# Rails seed.db syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this code. The first and second command for rails work good, but "project.todos << todo" part ruby interpreter treats like error.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `todos' for nil:NilClass
```

How can i fix it? When i put in seeds.rb text like this, all good, but with code it not work:

```
#work
project = Project.create title: "Family"
todo = Todo.create text: "Buy milk", isCompleted: true
project.todos << todo

#code
require 'yaml'
yhash = YAML.load_file(File.open("#{Rails.root}/db/seeds.yml"))
yhash.each do |key, value|
  value.each do |k, v|
    k.each do |ke, proj|
      if proj.class.name == 'String'
        project = Project.create title: proj
      elsif proj.class.name == 'Array'
        proj.each do |todo|
          i = 0
          tmp = ''
          todo.each do |to|
            to.each do |t|
              if i == 0
                i = 1
              elsif i == 2
                i = 3
              elsif i == 1
                tmp = t
                i  = 2
              elsif i == 3
                if t == false
                  bool = 'false'
                else
                  bool = 'true'
                end
                todo = Todo.create text: tmp, isCompleted: bool
                project.todos << todo
                i = 0
                tmp = ''
              end
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Short answer

You really should change your YAML structure, it would make everything much easier.

```
---
projects:
- title: Family
  todos:
  - text: Buy milk
    is_completed: true
  - text: Todo2
    is_completed: false
- title: Project2
  todos:
  - text: Todo3
    is_completed: true
  - text: Todo4
    is_completed: false
```

You could parse it in a few lines :

```
yaml = YAML.load(File.read('test.yaml'))

yaml['projects'].each do |project|
  title = project['title']
  p title
  # Create project here
  project['todos'].each do |todo|
    p todo
    # Create todo here
    # Add todo to project
  end
end
```

## NoMethodError

```
NoMethodError: undefined method 'todos' for nil:NilClass
```

means that the object on which `todos` is called (`project`) isn't defined.

Indeed, `project` isn't defined, but `proj` is, so you should create a `Project` called `project` first.

## Naming objects

To avoid confusion :

- `project_name` could be a string containing the project name
- `project_names` could be an array of project names
- `project` could be a `Project` object
- `todos` could be an Array of `Todo`s

Your code indicates that `proj` is used for different purposes :

```
project = Project.create title: proj
proj.each do |todo|
```

Those 2 `proj`s should be different objects with different variable names, and should be initialized separately.

It's easy to write nested hashes in YAML, one hash could represent `Project`s, the other could represent `Todo`s.

## Block variables

If you create a `Project` instance called `project` inside a loop during the first iteration, it will not be available to the next iterations :

```
[1, 2, 3].each do |i|
  if i==1
    project = "my project"
  end
  p i
  p project
end
# 1
# "my project"
# 2
# nil
# 3
# nil
```

If you want a `project` variable to be available to all iterations, you should create it **outside** of the loop :

```
project = "my project"
[1, 2, 3].each do |i|
  p i
  p project
end
# 1
# "my project"
# 2
# "my project"
# 3
# "my project"
```

Another possibility would be to use `@project` instead of `project` :

```
[1,2,3].each do |i|
  if i==1
    @project = "my project"
  end
  p i
  p @project
end
# 1
# "my project"
# 2
# "my project"
# 3
# "my project"
```

## case

Instead of :

```
if proj.class.name == 'String'
        project = Project.create title: proj
      elsif proj.class.name == 'Array'
```

You could use :

```
case proj
when String
  # proj is a String
when Array
  # proj is an Array
end
```

Comment: 'proj' is ruby array. 'project' - rails instance of the class. He is already created in block 'if proj.class.name == 'String''

Comment: But i have several different projects. 
For example:

`projects
  - title: 'family'
    todos:
    - text: 'Buy milk'
      isCompleted: false
    - text: 'Go to theatre'
    - isCompleted: false
  - title: 'work'
    todos:
    - text: 'Create code'
    - isCompleted: false
    ...`

Comment: It's not a pure ruby. It's command for rails db:seed, but pure ruby block this command because thing that is ruby class.

Comment: @HermanEyd It looks like you're mixing projects and todos in your YAML file, which makes your code more complex than necessary.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "pure ruby". Rake is pure Ruby.

Comment: This code works good:
`project = Project.create title: "Family"
todo = Todo.create text: "Buy milk", isCompleted: true
project.todos << todo`

And my script create the same code in out. 
In first case it work, but in second not because ruby think that is him class.

Comment: Before `k.each do |ke, proj|` i add `project = Project` and all work.